# Acessar menu mouseover por VBA

Tags: javascript, vba, classes, eventos-do-mouse

Necessito da ajuda de vocês!

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em VBA para extrair arquivos de um sistema interno da empresa, onde apos logado no site, a tela exibida tem um menubar por acesso a mouseouver, onde ao passar o mouse encima do menu "Relatórios" abre uma lista e no ultimo item da lista que é "Gerencial", onde preciso fazer um evento de click nele para prosseguir para a próxima tela, onde terei txtbox de data e turno e os botões para extrair os relatórios. Mas como ainda não consegui desenvolver a macro para selecionar o item "gerencial" do menubar, estou impossibilitado de prosseguir.

Resumindo, preciso que o VBA consiga chamar o menu relatorios do javascript onde esta o item gerencial e click para prosseguir para a proxima tela.

Segue abaixo parte do codigo Java do site onde estou tentando o acesso:

```
 <h1 id="nomeSist">
    IRCS - Sistema de Controle de Reparo e Inspeção
  </h1>
  <div id="menu_prime" class="ui-outputpanel ui-widget">
    <table border="0" class="menuStyle">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <form id="j_id196380812_76b57a10" name="j_id196380812_76b57a10" method="post" action="/tdb-rcs-report/framework/view/dashboard/dashboard.faces" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
              <div id="j_id196380812_76b57a10:j_id196380812_76b57a6a" class="ui-menu ui-menubar ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix" role="menubar">
                <div tabindex="0" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"></div>
                <ul class="ui-menu-list ui-helper-reset">
                  <li<li class="ui-widget ui-menuitem ui-corner-all ui-menu-parent" role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="true">
                    **<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="ui-menuitem-link ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1"><span class="ui-menuitem-text">Relatórios</span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span></a>**
                    <ul class="ui-widget-content ui-menu-list ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix ui-menu-child ui-shadow" role="menu">
                      <li class="ui-menuitem ui-widget ui-corner-all" role="menuitem">
                        <a tabindex="-1" class="ui-menuitem-link ui-corner-all" href="#" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({source:'j_id196380812_76b57a10:j_id196380812_76b57aa6',formId:'j_id196380812_76b57a10'});return false;"><span class="ui-menuitem-text">Diário</span></a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="ui-menuitem ui-widget ui-corner-all" role="menuitem">
                        <a tabindex="-1" class="ui-menuitem-link ui-corner-all" href="#" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({source:'j_id196380812_76b57a10:j_id196380812_76b57aab',formId:'j_id196380812_76b57a10'});return false;"><span class="ui-menuitem-text">Diário Reparo</span></a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="ui-menuitem ui-widget ui-corner-all" role="menuitem">
                        <a tabindex="-1" class="ui-menuitem-link ui-corner-all" href="#" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({source:'j_id196380812_76b57a10:j_id196380812_76b57ab8',formId:'j_id196380812_76b57a10'});return false;"><span class="ui-menuitem-text">Mensal Reparo</span></a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="ui-menuitem ui-widget ui-corner-all" role="menuitem">
                        <a tabindex="-1" class="ui-menuitem-link ui-corner-all" href="#" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({source:'j_id196380812_76b57a10:j_id196380812_76b57a8d',formId:'j_id196380812_76b57a10'});return false;"><span class="ui-menuitem-text">Defeitos por Imagem</span></a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="ui-menuitem ui-widget ui-corner-all" role="menuitem">
                        **<a tabindex="-1" class="ui-menuitem-link ui-corner-all" href="#" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({source:'j_id196380812_76b57a10:j_id196380812_76b57a92',formId:'j_id196380812_76b57a10'});return false;"><span class="ui-menuitem-text">Gerencial</span></a>**
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
```

Codigo VBA que estou usando:

```
    `Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument
Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorer

Sub Login()

Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim sURL As String
On Error GoTo Err_Clear
   sURL = "http://tdbsorsvr034/tdb-rcs-report/"
   'sURL = "http://tdbsorsvr034/tdb-rcs-report/reports/management/"
Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer
   oBrowser.Silent = True
   oBrowser.timeout = 60
   oBrowser.navigate sURL
   oBrowser.Visible = True

Do
Loop Until oBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set HTMLdoc = oBrowser.document
  HTMLdoc.all.j_username.Value = "BXIMENES"
  HTMLdoc.all.j_password.Value = "123456"
  HTMLdoc.all.loginBtnId.onclick
  'HTMLdoc.all.[ui-menuitem-link ui-corner-all].Value = "PrimeFaces.ab({source:'j_id196380812_76b57a10:j_id196380812_76b57a92',formId:'j_id196380812_76b57a10'})"




For Each oHTML_Element In HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
    If oHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then oHTML_Element.Click: Exit For

Next
Err_Clear:


Resume Next`
```

Desde ja agradeço a quem puder me ajudar!

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não descreveu o erro, o que dificulta um pouco ajudar.
Seu código (até a parte comentarizada) não contém uma condição adequada para clicar no link correto quando for encontrado, portanto meu primeiro palpite é de que o erro esteja aí. Além disso, perceba que `link` é uma coleção de objetos do tipo link HTML; cada link individual não é referenciado por essa variável, e sim pela variável usada para iterar o loop (ou seja, `l`, e não `link`).

```
    Set link = HTMLdoc.getelementsbytagname("a")
    For Each l In link
        If l.innertext = "Gerencial" Then 'Se isso não der certo, coloque um ponto de parada e use o debug para descobrir qual é o innertext do link correto. Às vezes o atributo pode conter espaços no início ou no fim, por exemplo. 
            l.Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next l
```

Comment: César obrigado pela ajuda! 
Então, meu código não abre erro algum apenas não executa nada após o acesso.  O site é intranet, após o login ele abre a tela inicial onde tem um menu dropdown com 2 itens e um deles é o “Relatórios” que ao passar o mouse encima abre uma lista com os itens e o último é o “gerencial” porém nao encontrei um id válido para ele e o link que tem para esta tela ele tem um esquema de atualização de primefaces que atualiza o final do link a cada acesso. Tipo um contador de acesso sei lá! Não entendo muito bem! Por isso não consigo usar o link pois não é fixo.

Comment: Na verdade eu encontrei esse código na web e fiz algumas alterações para usar ele. Porém agora achei um mais fácil de entendimento e passei a usar o outro código que alterei na pergunta

Comment: A parte relevante é o ```For... Each```, o resto é login. O login você disse que ele faz certinho, não é? Então vamos pra parte de clicar no menu "gerencial".

Comment: No HTML que você transcreveu, o atributo ```onclick``` que desejamos rodar está no elemento ```a```, ou seja: queremos clicar no elemento ```a``` correto. Pela sua explicação, o que temos para identificar o link é apenas o texto interno dele (ou a posição dentro dos elementos-pai, mas esse caminho pode ser muito vulnerável a alterações de leiaute).

Comment: Portanto, temos que iterar os elementos ```a```, até achar o que tem texto interno contendo "Gerencial".

Comment: É isso que o código que eu coloquei na resposta deveria fazer. Você testou ele? Mudei os nomes das variáveis de objeto para corresponderem ao seu código.

Comment: Isso César, a parte de entrar no site funciona perfeitamente, ainda não consegui testar o código que vc passou por conta de ser intranet e só consigo acessar na empresa. Desta forma devido ao feriado só retornaremos na quarta feira. Daí executivos teste e te informo ok? Muito obrigado mesmo por despender parte do seu tempo para me ajudar! Forte abraço e bom feriado!

Comment: Idem, abraço! Faço muitos scripts para minha empresa, e o pessoal aqui do Stack Overflow me ajudou muito, também! Fico feliz de poder ajudar. No aguardo.

Comment: show de bola! Tomara que funcione! Depois vou ir tentando fazer os próximos passos! E provavelmente vou precisar muito da sua ajuda e do fórum ;)

Comment: César bom dia! o código funcionou no modo de depuração. abriu certinho, porem ao executar sem depuração ele não abre. O que poderia estar ocorrendo? Não gerou nenhum código de erro. Será que tem a ver com o tempo de procura do elemento? precisaria colocar um temporizador par procurar? Só não sei fazer isso.

Comment: Isso já aconteceu comigo. É o seguinte: a página tem uma certa velocidade de carregamento. No modo de depuração, você deve ter dado pausas manualmente que deram tempo pra página carregar, mas no modo de execução, as pausas não acontecem e às vezes os elementos de que precisamos ainda não foram carregados!

Comment: O ```oBrowser.ReadyState``` não significa que a página acabou de carregar completamente, às vezes o navegador está ok mas uma parte assíncrona (carregada por ajax, algo assim) não veio ainda. Aí o código roda (o que é muito rápido), mas o link ainda não existe, por isso não acha o elemento correto e retorna um ```Empty```. A solução que usei foi colocar outro loop depois do loop do ```ReadyState```. Vou pro computador pegar um exemplo no meu código que deve servir pra você.

Comment: Hj a tarde consegui achar um post aqui do fórum e consegui colocar um temporizador. Até aí tudo bem! Agora estou em outro problema kkkk achei que conseguindo acessar a página seguinte onde tem os campos para inserir data, turno e botão de imprimir/ gerar relatórios em pdf fosse só chamar ele pelo HTMLDoc.all e o nome do form que já ia e não tá acontecendo :( vou deixar o código mais abaixo pra vc dar uma olhada se puder

Comment: Ok. Vou te adiantar uma coisa: minha primeira opção para driblar isso foi com temporizador, mas no trabalho a Internet era mais lenta, aí às vezes dava o tempo e não carregava o elemento, por isso percebi que o melhor era, depois do loop do ```readyState```, colocar outro loop em que ele fica testando se o link já existe.

Comment: Quanto à outra pergunta, marque essa como respondida, faça a outra e coloque o link aqui, para não ficar bagunçado.

Comment: Ok muito obrigado pela tão grande ajuda

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/437411/178178 Segue o novo post para a nova dúvida! Obrigado pela disposição César!

Comment: Se você puder marcar essa pergunta como respondida, me ajuda também

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada lá na outra.