# Como acessar menu mouseover com VBA

Tags: javascript, microsoft-excel, vba

Boa tarde!
Estou tentando automatizar o preenchimento de um formulário de um site, porém, estou com dificuldades de entrar no menu onde está o formulário.
Funciona assim: eu faço o login no site através de um userform, onde informo o usuário e senha e clico em "logar"... até ai ok, consegui fazer.
Após logar, preciso entrar em um menu que se expande quando passo o mouse em cima e ele abre outros submenus (+ 2 níveis). Preciso clicar no segundo nível de um desses submenus para visualizar o formulário e não estou conseguindo fazer a macro clicar. Não sei se consegui explicar bem, não conheço muito de programação. Vou deixar o código do VBA. Agradeço quem puder ajudar e se precisarem de mais informação, me avise que envio.
Obs.: achei essa postagem mas não funcionou no meu caso: [Acessar menu mouseover por VBA](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/436330/acessar-menu-mouseover-por-vba)

Sub Robo_APAC_1()

```
Dim IE As InternetExplorer

'Cria um objeto Internet Explorer
Set IE = New InternetExplorer
    
'Torna o objeto visível
IE.Visible = True

    'Navega ao site do SIGA Saúde
    IE.Navigate "http://siga.saude.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/sms/login.do?method=logoff"
            
    'Identifica se a página já foi totalmente carregada
    While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Wend
     
        'aguardar 3 segundos (se necessário)
        'sng = Timer
        'Do While sng + 3 > Timer
        'Loop
    
    IE.Document.All("j_username").Value = frmlogin.txbLogin
    IE.Document.All("j_password").Value = frmlogin.txbSenha
    IE.Document.All("confirmar").Click

'fehca a tela te login
Unload frmlogin
        
        'aguardar 2 segundos antes de validar o logon
        sng = Timer
        Do While sng + 2 > Timer
        Loop

'verifica se teve exito no login. Caso negativo, avisa o usuário e encerra a macro
i = IE.Document.body.getElementsbytagname("table")

If i Is Nothing Then GoTo continua

    If InStr(i.innertext, "Usuário ou senha inválido") > 0 Then
        IE.Quit
        MsgBox "Usuário ou senha inválido!", vbCritical, "Login"
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

continua:
Set link = IE.Document.body.getElementsbytagname("a")
For Each j In link
If j.innertext = "APAC" Then
j.Click
Exit For
End If
Next j

End Sub

Editado 17/02:

```html
MENU PRINCIPAL:

<div id="reg" style="left:297;width:100" onmouseover="handleMouseOver(event || evt)" onmouseout="handleMouseOut(event)" onclick="scheduleHideTree2(Tree.getElementNode(this))" class="">
    REGULAÇÃO
</div>


NIVEL 1:

<div id="reg_apac" onmouseover="handleMouseOver(event || evt)" onmouseout="handleMouseOut(event)" class="">
    APAC
</div>


NIVEL 2:

<div id="reg_preenchimento_solic" onmouseover="handleMouseOver(event || evt)" onmouseout="handleMouseOut(event)" onclick="setUrl(this,' http://siga.saude.prefeitura.sp.gov.br:80/sms/preenchimentoLaudo.do?method=initUseCaseAndInsert&amp;subsystem=apac')" class=""> 
    Preenchimento do Laudo de Solicitação
</div>
```

Imagem do menu: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoN8z.jpg

[image: HTML REGULACAO]

[image: CLIQUE]

[image: ERRO SCRIPT]

Comment: se é vba, remove a tag de `javascript`

Comment: Depende bastante do HTML da página, @Diego. Você não precisa movimentar o mouse para colocar em cima do menu, não. Esses menus geralmente são um conjunto organizado de tags ```DIV```, ```SPAN```, ```TABLE``` e afins, que ficam ocultas e vão tendo a visibilidade ajustada conforme o usuário aponte para uma ou outra.
O que você pode fazer é olhar qual é o elemento HTML em que você quer clicar, para enviar um evento click para ele.
Usando o Chrome, clique com o botão direito no elemento, depois ```Inspecionar```. Se não tiver aberto no lugar exato, repita a operação. Cole o HTML na pergunta.

Comment: Opa Cesar... primeiramente, obrigado pela sua atenção! Coloquei o código HTML de cada menu e submenu, veja se era assim que voce solicitou. Aproveitei e subi a imagem do menu, marcando à que se refere os códigos HTML que colei. Obrigado

Comment: @CésarRodriguez, bom dia! Adicionei uma imagem com o HTML do começo... o menu que estou tentando acessar é o "REGULAÇAO". Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Salve, Diego!

O lugar no qual você vai clicar apenas executa esse script `setUrl(this,' http://siga.saude.prefeitura.sp.gov.br:80/sms/preenchimentoLaudo.do?method=initUseCaseAndInsert&amp;subsystem=apac')`. Esse script não faz senão navegar para a página. Portanto, eu faria simplesmente o seguinte (...).

**EDIT:** Como não funcionou, a segunda tentativa é rodar o mesmo javascript que ele roda ao clicar (adaptando, é claro, o `this` da função para o elemento que seria referenciado por ele). As alterações foram a declaração da variável `JanelaAtual`, no começo, e o bloco final, depois do marcador `continua`.

```
Sub Robo_APAC_1()
    Dim JanelaAtual As HTMLWindowProxy
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    
    'Cria um objeto Internet Explorer
    Set IE = New InternetExplorer
        
    'Torna o objeto visível
    IE.Visible = True
    
    'Navega ao site do SIGA Saúde
    IE.navigate "http://siga.saude.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/sms/login.do?method=logoff"
            
    'Identifica se a página já foi totalmente carregada
    While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Wend
     
    'aguardar 3 segundos (se necessário)
    'sng = Timer
    'Do While sng + 3 > Timer
    'Loop
    
    IE.document.all("j_username").Value = frmLogin.txbLogin
    IE.document.all("j_password").Value = frmLogin.txbSenha
    IE.document.all("confirmar").Click
    
    'fehca a tela te login
    Unload frmLogin
        
        'aguardar 2 segundos antes de validar o logon
        sng = Timer
        Do While sng + 2 > Timer
        Loop
    
    'verifica se teve exito no login. Caso negativo, avisa o usuário e encerra a macro
    i = IE.document.body.getElementsByTagName("table")
    
    If i Is Nothing Then GoTo continua
    
    If InStr(i.innerText, "Usuário ou senha inválido") > 0 Then
        IE.Quit
        MsgBox "Usuário ou senha inválido!", vbCritical, "Login"
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
continua:
    Set JanelaAtual = IE.document.parentWindow
    JanelaAtual.execScript "setUrl(this, 'http://siga.saude.prefeitura.sp.gov.br:80/sms/preenchimentoLaudo.do?method=initUseCaseAndInsert&amp;subsystem=apac');"    
End Sub
```

Teste e diga se funcionou.

Comment: Cesar, boa tarde!  Tinha tentando fazer desta forma, mas, quando ele tentar navegar para este link, o sistema encerra a sessão do usuário e quando tento logar novamente, ele cai na tela inicial. Vou colocar o código completo do local que preciso clicar... mais uma vez, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Ok. Segunda tentativa: rodar o javascript que o clique rodaria. Diga se funcionou.

Comment: Salve Cesar... na hora de executar o JanelaAtual.execScript, deu o seguinte erro: "Erro em tempo de execução '-2147352319 (80020101)': Não foi possível concluir a operação. Erro: 80020101."    Vlw!

Comment: Talvez seja o ponto-e-vírgula no final. Tente colocar ```setUrl(document.getElementById('reg_preenchimento_solic'), 'http://siga.saude.prefeitura.sp.gov.br:80/sms/preenchimentoLaudo.do?method=initUseCaseAndInsert&amp;subsystem=apac');"``` (a única mudança é o ponto-e-vírgula entre o parêntese fechado e as aspas duplas).

Comment: Javascript tem que acabar as instruções com ponto-e-vírgula, mas o console do navegador dispensa, por isso, esqueci.

Comment: Opa mestre.... está parando no mesmo ponto, com o mesmo erro

Comment: Mais uma tentativa: colocar o "this", exatamente como está lá no link. Veja se funcionou.

Comment: Também não rolou. O que estive pensando: na linha de código que você passou, o getElementByID está entre aspas, o que torna ele uma string e o VBA não entende como um comando. Tentei setar o objeto e colocar fora das aspas, mas estou tomando erro na hora de setar o objeto (tipos incompatíveis). Ficou assim: `Set ThisObj = IE.Document.getElementById("reg_preenchimento_solic")
    JanelaAtual.execScript "setUrl(" & ThisObj & ", ' http://siga.saude.prefeitura.sp.gov.br:80/sms/preenchimentoLaudo.do?method=initUseCaseAndInsert&amp;subsystem=apac');" ` . Faz sentido? Vlw

Comment: Não é isso não, porque o argumento da função ```execScript``` é uma string (o script a ser rodado). O VBA nem se mete com o conteúdo do script. O que pode estar acontecendo é um erro no javascript, que retorna para o navegador como um erro e o navegador não está exibindo. Eu passei por isso esses dias.

Comment: Mas eu uso o selenium, pra poder controlar o Chrome, e o selenium devolve o erro do navegador.

Comment: Faz o seguinte... Adicione um ponto de parada na linha ```JanelaAtual.execScript``` e ride seu código. Quando ele chegar no ponto de parada, você vai até o Internet Explorer, abre o console e joga no console do navegador o código javascript (```setUrl(this, 'http://siga.saude.prefeitura.sp.gov.br:80/sms/preenchimentoLaudo.do?method=initUseCaseAndInsert&amp;subsystem=apac');```). Aí a gente vai saber se é no javascript o erro.

Comment: Em tese, ao rodar o script, ele deveria fazer a mesma coisa que acontece quando você clica na opção do menu.